# How to make a cocos2d game compatible with iPad3 without using HD images

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ipad-3

I have an iPad application. In this application I have used only normal images. This application is a game made in cocos2d. Apple rejected this application by giving the reason that it is not compatible with iPad 3. And images are not getting resized on this. Can anyone tell me that how can I make aaplication for iPad 3 without using high definition images?

Comment: You're at Apple's mercy here, if they declined it purely on the basis it doesn't use high res images, then **use high res images**

Comment: Yes, my first version was get approved,but in second version I am getting such problem.

Comment: Maybe the first version was approved, but they started taking notice of non-retina images by the time your update comes around. If Apple have said use high res images, use high res images. Open and shut case.

Comment: WDUK , it means there is no other way to avoid high definition images.

Comment: Why would you want to scale images anyway? You'll get the same result, ie no discernible improvement of image quality. The only option you have is to explicitly remove Retina iPad compatibility - if that is possible (Info.plist or iTunes perhaps). But it's just as likely that Apple is taking the stance of requiring Retina assets for Retina iPads (initially there may have been a grace period to allow legacy apps for a couple months).